# Shadow Killed enemies are still detected

Tags: dishonored

I had first 1, then 2 levels invested in the Shadow Kill skill during my playthrough of the Knife of Dunwall and Witches of Brigmore DLC for Dishonored. When I kill enemies, they dissolve and leave no body behind, as intended.

However, I've noticed that even though there are no bodies, enemies will still be able to detect that someone's been killed. I noticed that enemies will drop things like pistols and swords when they die, even though they leave no bodies behind.

Are the dropped items the things that are alerting the guards to the fact that someone died? Am I misunderstanding how Shadow Kill works? Or is this merely an unfortunate bug?

Comment: Cast Void Gaze before killing enemies, and see if the weapons make any noise when dropped. (You can hear them yourself in normal gameplay, but perhaps Void Gaze can tell you if *enemies* hear them as well.)

Comment: How are they "detecting" that someone's been killed? Is this happening when you kill them, or after they come across the spot where the kill occurred? (I.e. where the items were dropped)

Comment: @Ben NPCs will say things like "I think someone's lurking around" or something like that, and will go on alert. This isn't after I just killed someone, they'll come across a spot where I shadow killed someone earlier, but there's no corpse.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for an answer to this and discovered similarly confused players.

[Odd Shadow Kill Experience](https://steamcommunity.com/app/205100/discussions/0/616198900637209984/)

However, I did find one possible explanation. According to IGN, you can't Shadow Kill someone in a conversation unnoticed. This makes me wonder that, as the NPCs wander, they expect to "check in" with other NPCs. If you Shadow Kill one and the other NPC can't "talk" to him or her, maybe they get alarmed.

[IGN: Shadow Kill](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dishonored/Shadow_Kill)